# не работает сортировка пузырьком

Tags: javascript, пузырьковая-сортировка

код:

```
let t;      
let arr = [2,1,0];
let check = true;
while(check);
check = false;
for(let j = 0; j<=arr.length-2; j++) {
    if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
        check = true;
        t = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j+1];
        arr[j+1] = t;
    }
}
```

получается вечный цикл, хотя логика такова: первый цикл (while) должен крутиться пока не будет доказан тот факт, что за весь проход по массиву arr нет ни одной пары элементов, которая идет по убыванию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Уберите точку с запятой после `while(check)`:

```
while (check) {
  ...
}
```