# не получается обменять элементы массива местами, при определенных обстоятельствах

Tags: массивы, индексы

есть код:
`

```
let arr1 = [24,17];

for(let i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
        let arr = [arr[i]];
        arr1[i] = arr;
    }
    document.write(arr1 +  "<br/>");
    for(let i = 0, j = 0; i<=(arr1/2 - 1); i++, j++) {
        if(arr1[i][0] > arr1[i+1][0]) {
            let arr_new = [arr1[i+1][0],arr1[i][0]];
            arr1[j] = arr_new;
            arr1.splice(i+1,1);
        } else if(arr1[i][0] < arr1[i+1][0]) {
            let arr_new = [arr1[i][0],arr1[i+1][0]]; //[ [[24],[17]], ]
            arr1[j] = arr_new;
            arr1.splice(i+1,1);
        }
    }

    document.write(arr1);
```

1. 

эта часть:

```
        for(let i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
        let arr = []; 
        arr[0] = arr1[i];
        arr1[i] = arr;
}
```

заполняет каждый элемент массива `arr1` массивами, но просто с тем значениями, которые были у него сначала. То есть если был arr1 === `[5,9]`, то должен получиться arr1 === `[[5],[9]]`

2. данный код:

```
        for(let i = 0, j = 0; i<=(arr1/2 - 1); i++, j++) {
              if(arr1[i][0] > arr1[i+1][0]) {
                 let arr_new = [arr1[i+1][0],arr1[i][0]];
                 arr1[j] = arr_new;
                 arr1.splice(i+1,1);
           } else if(arr1[i][0] < arr1[i+1][0]) {
              let arr_new = [arr1[i][0],arr1[i+1][0]];
              arr1[j] = arr_new;
              arr1.splice(i+1,1);
           }
        }
```

должен, по идее, сравнивать значения элементов массивов (то есть массивы из одного элемента) попарно, и если один из элементов массива arr1 является большим, чем другой, то они должны объединиться вместе в одном массиве `let arr_new = [arr1[i+1][0],arr1[i][0]];`, при этом меняясь местами.
Далее, мы удаляем следующий элемент массива `arr1` -  `arr1.splice(i+1,1)`, если i == 0, то удалиться должен элемент со значением `17`, то есть с индексом 1.
В итоге мы должны получить arr1 === `[[[17],[24]]];`, но получается лишь так, что элемент с индексом 0 равен 24, а с индексом 1 равен 17. Я ожидал другого результата, а именно, что они поменяются местами.

Comment: `arr1[j] = arr_new;  arr1.splice(i+1,1);` вот это я бы вынес из блока `if` в блок `for`, а конструкцию `else if` вообще бы разобрал удалив лишний `if`, она имеет избыточность с точки зрения оптимальности скорее всего

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем коде есть опечатки. Например, вот здесь

```
let arr = [arr[i]];
```

`arr[i]` откуда возьмется?

**Вот это `(arr1/2 - 1)` в условии цикла, как Вы думаете, чему равно?**

Зачем в цикле нужна переменная `j`? Она же все время равна `i`.

Сделайте в вопросе работающий пример, воспроизводящий то, что Вы наблюдаете.

Comment: `let arr = [arr[i]];` нет в моем коде, он есть здесь лишь потому, что я добавил его после, при редактировании бессмысленной строчки, но это неважно.
Спасибо за указание на эту ошибку `(arr1/2 - 1)`, все заработало

Comment: @ДмитрийВорончев Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: @ДмитрийВорончев Здесь - тоже: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1183119/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b7%d1%8b%d1%80%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc

Comment: здесь есть возможность приглашать в чат по обсуждению проблемы или нечто подобное?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com вот так например? Ссылка внизу страницы подробности тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms